# A problem between using Chinese and bigfoot

Tags: bigfoot

I am writing a Chinese book. When I using `\package{bigfoot}` with the `\usepackage[heading]{ctex}`, it does not work properly. Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[total={6in, 8in}]{geometry} % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.

%% 顯示中文
\usepackage[heading]{ctex} %代替了\usepackage{ctexcap}



%% 備註   % 對表格的備注只能使用\footnote{text}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcounter{footalt}
\def\thefootalt{\fnsymbol{footalt}}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footalt}
\WithSuffix\def\footnotedefault'{\refstepcounter{footalt}
    \Footnotedefault{\thefootalt}}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}  % footref 的應用。要放在 hyperref 之前。
%\usepackage{hyperref} % 可讓你點擊ref 直接指向所 ref, 譬如點擊 TOC, 可以去到相應章節. 要放在 footmisc 之後
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[arabic]
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{C}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{D}[Roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{E}[Alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{F}[fnsymbol]
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteC}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteD}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteE}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteF}

\newcommand{\lb}{\label}

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{3mm} 






%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

It is highly\footnoteF{footnote f to the text} recommended to add a compilable, \footnoteA{this\footnoteF{footnoteF to footnote} is a \footref{001}first-level\footnoteB{\lb{001}this is a \footref{002}second-level\footnoteC{\lb{002}footnote\footnoteD{footnote d} c} footnote sample.} foonote sample.}but minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. This way other users can compile it themselves, analyze error messages more closely and also easily implement and test their solutions before posting them. This allows also for full, compilable examples to be posted in the answers which are very helpful for the question asker and all other people with the same problem. Note that in (La)TeX, issues are often dependent on the packages used, and other people won't be able to provide much help if they don't know which packages you are using.

"中文中文中文"

\end{document}
```

In this example, the Chinese characters and the `\footnoteF{footnoteF to footnote}` cannot work together at the same time. They appear separately by using `\usepackage[heading]{ctex}` or not.
How can I make both appearing at the same time? Thanks!

Comment: Which engine, which texsystem and which OS do you use?

Answer (score 1):

This seems quite similar to [While loading fancyvrb, siunitx and bigfoot, I got input stack size=5000, TeX STOPPED: fatal errors occurred](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/403651/4427) and the same solution applies:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[total={6in, 8in}]{geometry} % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.

%% 顯示中文
\usepackage[heading,fontset=ubuntu]{ctex} %代替了\usepackage{ctexcap}



%% 備註   % 對表格的備注只能使用\footnote{text}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\FN@allmarks}{266}{256}{}{} % patch bigfoot to use the right counter
\makeatother


\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcounter{footalt}
\def\thefootalt{\fnsymbol{footalt}}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footalt}
\WithSuffix\def\footnotedefault'{\refstepcounter{footalt}
    \Footnotedefault{\thefootalt}}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}  % footref 的應用。要放在 hyperref 之前。
%\usepackage{hyperref} % 可讓你點擊ref 直接指向所 ref, 譬如點擊 TOC, 可以去到相應章節. 要放在 footmisc 之後
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[arabic]
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{C}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{D}[Roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{E}[Alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{F}[fnsymbol]
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteC}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteD}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteE}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteF}

\newcommand{\lb}{\label}

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{3mm} 






%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

It is highly\footnoteF{footnote f to the text} recommended to add a compilable, \footnoteA{this\footnoteF{footnoteF to footnote} is a \footref{001}first-level\footnoteB{\lb{001}this is a \footref{002}second-level\footnoteC{\lb{002}footnote\footnoteD{footnote d} c} footnote sample.} foonote sample.}but minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. This way other users can compile it themselves, analyze error messages more closely and also easily implement and test their solutions before posting them. This allows also for full, compilable examples to be posted in the answers which are very helpful for the question asker and all other people with the same problem. Note that in (La)TeX, issues are often dependent on the packages used, and other people won't be able to provide much help if they don't know which packages you are using.

"中文中文中文"

\end{document}
```

I added `fontset=ubuntu` just in order to be able to run the example and it's irrelevant for the solution.